# The time will come when your dream (will?) come true

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, future-tense

According to [Swan Practical English Usage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0194420981) (Don't say it! 130 common mistakes, page:xxvi);

Don't say / write:

> I will phone you when I will arrive.

Say / write:

> I will phone you when I arrive.

**Q:** Is that always the case, or there is more to it?

See for example the following, which I (a non-native English speaker) find to be fine;

> The time will come when your dream will come true.

Comment: The example with "I will phone you when I will arrive " of course sounds unnatural, but the sentence you've written(your time will come) ,sounds just fine.(at least to me,and I can be wrong). In fact if you drop that "will",this sentence  will sound unnatural.

Comment: Ah, well, if you dropped the second *will* in that example it would sound wrong - but only because *come* would then not be conjugated correctly. If you also make it *comes*, then it sounds fine again. However, the 'problem' remains that it is fine *with* the *will*, seemingly in contradiction of the 'rule'. I shall have to give that some thought as to how to explain - it's one of these things native speakers don't even think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will phone you when I arrive.

This is a conditional statement. You are saying that you *will* phone (future action) when the condition is met (that you arrive).

> The time will come when your dream will come true.

Despite having a similar sentence structure, "when" in this example does not denote a condition. The meaning is that your dreams *will* come true at a future time that *will* come.

Answer (score 0):

Simple present is used instead of the simple future tense, in clauses of time and of condition.

> I shall wait till you finish your lunch.
>
> If it rains I will not go out.

In the sentence **A time will come when your dream will come true**. There is no condition. Hence it is fine.